# jQuery UI CSS not overriding

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, inheritance, overriding

I have some anchor icons that inherit from `.ui-widget-content` and `.ui-state-default`. The `background-position` of `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default` is overriding the `background-position` of `.ui-icon-play`.

When the anchor icons only inherit from `.ui-state-default`, the background-position of `.ui-icon-play` has higher priority than that of `.ui state default`.

I want `.ui-icon-play` to override `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default` so that I get the correct icon image from the image sprite. 
How does the priority get decided when they are both classes and according to chrome dev tools, `.ui-icon-play` is line 232 of the ui css whereas the `.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default` is line 69?

Also when I do `addClass('.ui-icon-play')`, the `background-position` still doesn't override that of the `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default`.

Here is simplified version of my code:

**html**

```
<div class="controls-container ui-widget-content">
    <div class="rep-controls">
        <a id="play" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-play" 
               title="Play/Pause"></a>
        <a id="stop" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-stop" 
               title="Stop"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$("#play").click(function() {
    if(playing == true) {
        $("#play").removeClass('ui-icon-pause');
    else {
        $("#play").addClass('ui-icon-pause');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you are able to modify the CSS, just try making the selector:

```
.ui-widget-content a.ui-icon-play {[...]}
```

Adding the 'a' will make the selector override `.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default` because it is more specific.

Comment: I don't understand where in the code I would be using this, can you elaborate?

Answer (score -1):

Go for specifity or !important